# Vue.js - Creating a Admin and a User Panel - Best practice

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, backend, vue-router

i am new to programming with vue.
i am currently building my first vue frontend app with a node.js backend server.
There should be 2 different apps in the frontend.

confuguration panel for admins (www.websitename.com/admin)
user who uses the website. (www.websitename.com)
Is it useful to create 2 separate apps for such a case?
Or is it best practice to have both in one SPA?

If it makes more sense to have 2 separate apps (to prevent the complete code (including the admin code) from being sent to the user on the user side) how would that be handled best?

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both together. 
To prevent normal user navigate to admin page, can try to use vue router navigation guard to protect it.